# Convert string to time

Tags: code-golf, date, natural-language

This challenge is inspired by [this other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71203/convert-the-time-to-a-string).

## The challenge

Write a program or a function in any programming language that given as input a string representing a time in English (see below, for further details) it outputs or prints the equivalent in the 24 hours "digital" format HH:MM.

Shortest code in bytes wins, [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

## Input format

Your program should be able to handle all this kind of inputs:

```
one minute past 'HOUR'
'MINUTES' minutes past 'HOUR'
quarter past 'HOUR'
half past 'HOUR'
one minute to 'HOUR'
'MINUTES' minutes to 'HOUR'
quarter to 'HOUR'
'HOUR'
'HOUR12' 'MINUTES' AM
'HOUR12' 'MINUTES' PM
```

where: `MINUTES` is a number from 1 to 59 written in English with hyphen; `HOUR` is the name of an hour in one of the formats:

```
midnight
noon
midday
'HOUR24' o'clock
'HOUR12' o'clock AM
'HOUR12' o'clock PM
```

`HOUR12` is a number from 1 to 12 written in English with hyphen; and `HOUR24` is a number from 1 to 23 written in English with hyphen.

## Some examples

```
midnight                                  ->   00:00
midday                                    ->   12:00
twelve o'clock                            ->   12:00
quarter to midnight                       ->   23:45
twenty-two minutes past eight o'clock PM  ->   20:22
thirty-four minutes to fifteen o'clock    ->   14:26
six o'clock AM                            ->   06:00
one minute to twenty-one o'clock          ->   20:59
seven thirteen AM                         ->   07:13
nine fourteen PM                          ->   21:14
```

Good luck!

Comment: So is `'MINUTES'` minutes past `'HOUR24' o'clock` a valid time?

Comment: @muddyfish Yes, it is.

Comment: Should `HOUR24` be a number from *0* to 23?

Comment: @ETHproductions No, from 1 to 23. "zero o'clock" doesn't sound well.

Comment: @Bob neither does "24 o-clock" or "23-oclock"

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>653</s> 597 Bytes

```
P=/ past | to /;T=%w{q twen thirty fourty fifty sixty el twe thi fourte fifte sixt sevent eighte ninet o tw th fo fi si s e n t}.zip([15,*(2..6).map{|i|i*10},*11..19,*1..10]).to_h;D={'middnight'=>0,'midday'=>12,'noon'=>12};n=->s{s.split('-').reduce(0){|p,v|(Array(T.find{|k,_|v.start_with? k}).last||0)+p}};i=->s{m=0;s=s.gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');c=s.split(P);(c.reverse! if s.match(P));h=D[c[0]]||n.(c[0].gsub(/ o\'clock (A|P)m/,''));h+=(s.end_with?('PM') ? 12 : 0);m=n.(c[1]||c[0].split(' ')[1]) if c[1]||c[0].match(/^\w+ (?!o'clock)/);(m=60-m;h=(h-1)%24)if s.match(/ to /);(sprintf '%02d:%02d',h,m)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
P=/ past | to /
# configuration for translating english words to numbers
T=%w{q twen thirty fourty fifty sixty el twe thi fourte fifte sixt sevent eighte ninet o tw th fo fi si s e n t}.zip([15,*(2..6).map{|i|i*10},*11..19,*1..10]).to_h
D={'middnight'=>0,'midday'=>12,'noon'=>12}

# proc for translating english word groups to a number
n=-> s {
  s.split('-').reduce(0) { |p,v|
    (Array(T.find {|k,_| v.start_with? k}).last || 0) + p
  }
}

i=-> s {
  m=0
  s=s.gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'')
  c=s.split(P)
  (c.reverse! if s.match(P))

  # set the hour
  h=D[c[0]]||n.(c[0].gsub(/ o\'clock (A|P)m/,''))
  h+=(s.end_with?('PM') ? 12 : 0)

  # set the minute
  m=n.(c[1]||c[0].split(' ')[1]) if c[1]||c[0].match(/^\w+ (?!o'clock)/)

  # adjust for 'past'
  (m=60-m;h=(h-1)%24)if s.match(/ to /)

  sprintf '%02d:%02d',h,m
}
```

Verification script used:

```
examples = <<EXAMPLES
midnight                                  ->   00:00
midday                                    ->   12:00
twelve o'clock                            ->   12:00
quarter to midnight                       ->   23:45
twenty-two minutes past eight o'clock PM  ->   20:22
thirty-four minutes to fifteen o'clock    ->   14:26
six o'clock AM                            ->   06:00
one minute to twenty-one o'clock          ->   20:59
seven thirteen AM                         ->   07:13
nine fourteen PM                          ->   21:14
EXAMPLES

examples.split("\n").each do |example|
  text, expected = example.split(/\s+->\s+/)
  r = i.(text)
  raise "Unexpected result for \"#{text}\". Got \"#{r}\", expected \"#{expected}\"" unless r == expected
  print "."
end
```

Thank you to Kevin Lau for 47 bytes of optimization

Comment: `[15,*(2..6).map{|i|i*10},*11..19,*1..10]` is a much more concise representation of the numbers you are using to construct your hash. Also, there's a lot of whitespace you can remove between brackets, and using Ruby interpolation within regex patterns allows you to replace `v.start_with? k` with `v=~/^#{k}/`

Comment: I should have thought of the ranges and splats, thanks! Also removed some unnecessary whitespace.